# Скопировать 3 файла из родительского каталога

Tags: c, unix, find

Мне требуется создать каталог с именем передаваемым через параметр при вызове и скопировать 3 файла из родительского каталога в этот каталог.

Код программы на Си:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
struct dirent *dirbuf;
DIR *fddir;
mkdir(argv[1], 0777); 
int result;
result = chdir(argv[1]);
if(result != 0)
   printf("Не могу перейти к каталогу %s\n",
                  argv[1]);
else
   printf("Текущим стал каталог %s\n", argv[1]);
system("find .. -type f -exec cp '{}' . ';'); //копируются 
                                              //все файлы из 
                                              //родительской 
                                              //директории

dir = opendir("."); //open current directory
if (dir == NULL) //if the directory cannot be open
{
  printf("Error! Enable to open directory.\n");
  exit(1);
}
else
{
  printf("Files in curret directory:\n");
  system("find . -type f -exec ls -l ‘{}’ ‘;’");
}

return 0;
}
```

Я в этой программе копирую все файлы из родительской директории, а мне нужно 3. Подскажите, как мне это сделать. Какие три в задании не сказано, думаю любые.

Comment: Уточните то, какие файлы копировать. Либо их через параметры передать либо получите список и рандомно выберите.

Comment: >_< я понимаю, что `system()` — это универсальный молоток, но если это учебное задание, подозреваю, что от тебя хотели использование и других системных вызовов... если всё же придерживаться выбранного пути и считать задачу обычным гвоздём, то можешь собрать конвеер (те забавно выглядищие команды с палками `|` посередине); помимо уже известного `cp` и `find` или `ls` тебе пригодятся утилиты `head` и `xargs`.

Answer (score 0):

Команда

```
ls | tail -n3 | xargs rm
```

удалит три последних (в смысле *ls) файла в директории.
Вместо *ls* поставите *find* с нужными параметрами, вместо *rm* - *cp*.